# Java LinkedHashMap replace key

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there any way to replace a key using `put()` in a LinkedHashMap without losing the order that the key was originally inserted in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used the LinkedHashMap, I don't think there is built-in method to achieve your goal. You may want to pick another (or design your own) data-structure.

If you have to do it on a linkedhashmap, you can create a new LinkedHashMap, iterate the old one and put into the new one, when your target entry comes, create a new entry with different key, put the new entry into the map.

Answer (score 10):

You do not lose the order when putting a different value for the same key.

**Example**

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo", "bar");
map.put("blah", "baz");
System.out.println(map);
map.put("foo", "foo");
System.out.println(map);
```

**Output**

```
{foo=bar, blah=baz}
{foo=foo, blah=baz}
```

**Edit**

"Replacing" a key for a given value would imply removing the key value pair, then putting the new key with the stored value.

As such, there is no direct way to do this with a `LinkedHashMap`, probably not even by inheriting and changing the behavior of `remove` and `put`.